# Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await Bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.online, activity =discord.Streaming(name = '!helps', url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/ivankolobo'))

RPC = Presence(Client Id)

btns = [
    {
        "label": "VK",
        "url": ""
    }
]

RPC.connect()
RPC.update(
    state = 'Джойстик',
    details = 'Красивый джойстик',
    buttons = btns,
    large_image = '2',
    small_image = 'unnamed',
    large_text = 'Джойстик',
    small_text = 'Котик'
)

print(Bot.user.name + " is ready.")
```

Выходит ошибка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3):

Функция `RPC.connect()` является ассинхронной, и её нужно вызывать так:

```
await RPC.connect()
```